# adding JTextArea to JMapViewer?

Tags: swing, jmapviewer

Can we add JTextArea to JMapViewer? Something like

```
JMapViewer map() = new JMapViewer();
map.add(new JTextArea(10,10));
```

Another workaround can be adding it to GridBagLayout within JFrame/JInternalFrame, but I want to know that is possible to show text within a map?

Comment: what happened when you tried ;-)

Comment: like if you do textArea.setText("Wie Gehts?") it just shows a grey screen with no text in it.